# Better algorithm to find difference of two resultsets in java

Tags: java, ms-access, resultset

I need to compare two resultsets and find the difference between them.
both will have same columns. The operation is A-B i.e from source to target and finding which rows were present in source but not in target.

The code:

```
        ResultSetMetaData metaSrc = rsSrc.getMetaData();
        ResultSetMetaData metaTgt = rsTgt.getMetaData();
        final int columnCountSrc = metaSrc.getColumnCount();

        Boolean rowFound=true;

        List<Integer> tgtPassedRowList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> srcPassedRowList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<DBRow> DataInSourceNotInTarget = new ArrayList<DBRow>();
        List<DBRow> DataInTargetNotInSource = new ArrayList<DBRow>();

    if(ExecCondition.equals("Source To Target"))
        {
            int srcCounter = 0;
            while(rsSrc.next())
            {
                srcCounter++;
                int tgtCounter = 0;
                rsTgt.beforeFirst();
                    innerloop:while(rsTgt.next())
                    {
                        tgtCounter++;

                        //Object tgtColumn1 = rsTgt.getObject(1);
                        if(!tgtPassedRowList.contains(tgtCounter))
                        {
                            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
                            {
                                Object srcColumn = rsSrc.getObject(column);
                                Object tgtColumn = rsTgt.getObject(column);
                                if(!srcColumn.equals(tgtColumn))
                                {
                                    rowFound = false;
                                        //System.out.println("ValueSRC: "+srcColumn.toString());
                                    //System.out.println("ValueTgt: "+tgtColumn.toString());

                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            if(rowFound)
                            {

                                    passedRowList.add(srcCounter);
                                    tgtPassedRowList.add(tgtCounter);
                                    break innerloop;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                failedRows++;
                                if(rsTgt.isLast())
                                {
                                    DBRow d2 = new DBRow();
                                    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
                                    {
                                        d2.Row.add(rsSrc.getObject(column));
                                    }
                                    DataInSourceNotInTarget.add(d2);
                                }
                            }
                        }//if contains
                    }

            }
            for(DBRow o:DataInSourceNotInTarget)
            {
                o.print();
            }

        } //if source to target
```

DBRow Class:

```
public class DBRow {

public List<Object> Row;

public DBRow()
{
    Row = new ArrayList<Object>();
}

public void print()
{
    for(Object obj:Row)
    {
        System.out.print(obj.toString()+" ");
    }
}
}
```

This code take more than an hour for comparing two resultsets with 10 columns and 10000 records.(its still running and i havent got the result) That means its not a good solution.

This code takes a row from source and compares with target, as soon as it finds, it breaks the `while(rsTgt.next())` loop and gets another source row to compare.

one thing you can notice is that i put `if(!tgtPassedRowList.contains(tgtCounter))` to lower the source row comparison with already passed rows in target. but i cannot make the cursor jump to rows which were not passed.

that means for every row in source it will go to every row in target. 
10000 * 10000 = 100,000,000.

Can you guys point out what could be the possible solution to make it more faster.

is using a resultset a problem or is there a better way to write this.

PS: 10000 records are in MSAccess db. this will be used for an oracle repository, i dont have it right now , so i am using access.

Comment: It is possible to delegate this operation to the database? It is the most correct instrument to do that.